# Why can't I install a custom font in Win32 under FMX?

Tags: delphi, fonts, firemonkey, pascal

I've tried `AddFontResourceEx()`. But it only works in VCL. Android can modify the IDE source code to load fonts. I think it may be related to Direct2D. Only after manually installing fonts into the system can I enumerate my custom fonts.

I am here: https://github.com/TheOriginalBytePlayer/FireMonkey-Fonts

It seems to be a feasible solution, but it's not smooth.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! If I understand what you say, you have working code for Windows and you need to port that code to Android. Is it correct? Please show the code you have and the issue you see.

Comment: Thank you. What I need is to install fonts in FMX Win32. At present, he can only succeed in VCL

Comment: As far as I know, FMX/Win32 is using fonts from Windows system. You must install a font in/with Windows and then you can use it in your program. If you deploy your program, you must deploy the fonts you use with it and have your program's installer install the fonts on the target system. Of course you can embed the font setup (temporarily) into your application using win32 API: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/gdi/font-installation-and-deletion

Comment: I need embed the font setup (temporarily) into my application using win32 API.But this function（AddFontResourceEx()） can only be used in VCL, I can't use it in FMX.

Comment: WinAPI is independent of framework. What error do you get EXACTLY. Show YOUR code. Edit you question to add the information.

Comment: I think the project in GitHub can solve my problems.But I found that this project needs to package fonts into res. There is no demo to refer to. I tried: 1 rcdata“ my.ttf "Or 1 font" my.ttf ", all failed. If it works, I think my problem should be solved.

Comment: Are you expecting that I look at it and debug it? Edit your question (Do NOT add one more comment) with your tries and the error messages you get and exactly where you get it. Also try to contact the author and/or create an issue in his GitHub repository. Last note: please read this: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: OK, thank you very much. I'm going to create another topic.